# Plot multiple curves of one changing value in Python Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, numerical-methods

I'm coding an Euler method and I would like to plot in one figure different curves when "h" or step size changes its value, without making new variables for each h. Is there an easy way to do it?

Here's my code and after it an example of the graph I'd like. Thanks !

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sol = lambda x: exp(x**2/2)

dy = lambda x,y: x*y #Ecuacion Dif

sol2 = np.vectorize(sol)

x = 0 #intervalo

xn = 2 #intervalo mayor

y = 1 #VALOR INICIAL

h = 0.5 #STEP SIZE

n = int((xn - x)/h)
print("x \t\t y(Euler)\t y (Analitica)")
print("{0} \t {1} \t {2}".format(x,y,sol(x)))

yg = [y]
xg = [x]
xr = np.arange(0,n*h,0.01)

for i in range(n):

    y += dy(x,y)*h

    yg.append(y)

    x += h

    xg.append(x)

    print("{0:.5f} \t {1:.5f} \t {2:.5f}".format(x,y,sol(x)))

plt.plot(xr,sol2(xr),color='k',label='Analitca')
plt.plot(xg,yg,color='b',label="h = 0.5")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Metodo de Euler')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('Euler_Metodo.png')
plt.show()
```

[Graph that I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmfbP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I did after some work. I hope someone finds it helpful!

```
from math import exp
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

sol = lambda x: exp(x**2/2)
dy = lambda x,y: x*y #Ecuacion Dif
sol2 = np.vectorize(sol)
x = 0 #intervalo
xn = 2 #intervalo mayor
y = 1 #VALOR INICIAL
h = [1,0.5,0.2,0.05,0.01] #dif values h
nlista = []

for valor in range(len(h)):
    x = 0
    nlista.append(int((xn - x)/h[valor]))
    print(nlista)

for j in range(len(h)):
    x = 0
    y = 1
    yg = [1]
    xg = [0]


    for i in range(nlista[j]):


        y += dy(x,y)*h[j]

        yg.append(y)

        x += h[j]

        xg.append(x)

        #print("{0:.5f} \t {1:.5f} \t {2:.5f}".format(x,y,sol(x)))


    plt.plot(xg,yg,label="h = {0}".format(h[j]))
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('y')
    plt.title('Metodo de Euler')


xr = np.arange(0,2,0.01)
plt.plot(xr,sol2(xr),color='k',label='Analitca')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.savefig('Euler_Metodo.png')
plt.show()
```

Here's the result:

[RESULTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJaBC.png)